# How to select all hrefs that don't start with two ".." (dots) in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to select specific lines in an html document using regex.
I'm looking to select lines starting with `<link` and that do NOT contain in the `href` the characters `../`

Here's part of the html I have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/IP_Master_PT_RTL.master.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../global.design-editor.com/v8/main.min1024.css?v=_STAGING-Publisher_20180327.1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/alefhebrew.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ad-systems368c.css?v=4701716615" />
```

This is what i did so far:
`<link[^\*]*?href=[^\*]*?"[^..]*`
I'm getting close but i would like to select the whole tag and not have the other tags selected.

I just started learning about regex so i'm fairly new to this.

Comment: *"I'm trying to select specific lines in an html document using regex."* [Don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454), it can't be done reliably. If you need to work with HTML, use an HTML parser.

Comment: if you are doing this in browser using javascript, you can use dom apis to read all link elements and then do regex or string match for href check. sample:

```document.querySelectorAll('link').forEach((linkelement,i)=>{
   console.log(linkelement.attributes['href']);
})```

Answer (score 3):

Using JavaScript in the browser, you can just look up all `<link>` elements and then filter them based on the `href` attribute

```js
let allLinks = document.querySelectorAll('link');

let filteredLinks = Array.from(allLinks)
  .filter(el => el.getAttribute("href").startsWith("../") == false);

console.log(filteredLinks);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/IP_Master_PT_RTL.master.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../global.design-editor.com/v8/main.min1024.css?v=_STAGING-Publisher_20180327.1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/alefhebrew.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ad-systems368c.css?v=4701716615" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const links = [...document.getElementsByTagName('link')];
const newLinks = links.filter(link => !link.outerHTML.includes('../'))
console.log(newLinks)
```

Comment: `.includes` will catch that sequence anywhere in the string. In fact, anywhere in the entire HTML for that element.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I didn't know about `getAttribute`. Your solution is much better

Answer (score -2):

Maybe he/she is analysing files so he/she needs ragex.
So here is my solution...

I am also new to ragex, but this might work for you.

```
<link\s*.*href\=\"[^(\.\.\/)].*\".*/>
```

also check [this ragex builder](https://regexr.com/), have fun..

Comment: It's r**e**gex - for Regular Expression. And this pattern will not match `href='../somevalue'` because of the quotes. The character class inside 1. doesn't need any escapes 2. will not match *only* `../` but also `.` or `./` or `/`. This can also match something you didn't intend at all, for example with the HTML `'<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/alefhebrew.css" /><a href="abc"></a><br/>'`